# Producing XML from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Can somebody help me with producing XML from two sql tables?

This is what I want:

```
<Sales>
  <Sale>
    <Journal_Prime>400000</Journal_Prime>
    <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
          <Account>700300</Account>
          <Amount>276,79</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>WD2093E0V0</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>708000</Account>
          <Amount>0,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>Korting</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>700530</Account>
          <Amount>55,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>Transport</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>451000</Account>
          <Amount>0,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>11</Ventil>
          <Ref>BTW</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
  </Sale>
</Sales>
```

This is my attempt

```
SELECT Sale.Journal_Prime, Sale.DocNumber, Detail.Account, Detail.Account, Detail.Amount, Detail.DebCre, Detail.Ventil, Detail.Ref, Detail.DocNumber
FROM XML_FAKAdres2017  as Sale 

INNER JOIN XML_FAK2017 as Detail
ON Sale.DocNumber = Detail.DocNumber

FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Sales'), ELEMENTS
```

giving me this result

```
<Sales>
  <Sale>
    <Journal_Prime>400000</Journal_Prime>
    <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        <Detail>
          <Account>700300</Account>
          <Amount>276,79</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>WD2093E0V0</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>708000</Account>
          <Amount>0,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>Korting</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>700530</Account>
          <Amount>55,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>70</Ventil>
          <Ref>Transport</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <Account>451000</Account>
          <Amount>0,00</Amount>
          <DebCre>-1</DebCre>
          <Ventil>11</Ventil>
          <Ref>BTW</Ref>
          <DocNumber>100001</DocNumber>
        </Detail>
  </Sale>
</Sales>
```

So, I'm missing the `<Details></Details>` which is required by the bookkeeping program this code is meant for import.  I'm not familiar with XML and to be honest I don't have a clue where this coming from.

Thanks.
Rik

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to help people need some data to work with. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Sale.Journal_Prime, Sale.DocNumber , 
(SELECT Detail.Account, Detail.Account, Detail.Amount, 
Detail.DebCre, Detail.Ventil, Detail.Ref, Detail.DocNumber
FROM XML_FAK2017 as Detail where Sale.DocNumber = Detail.DocNumber
FOR XML AUTO,TYPE,ROOT('Details'),ELEMENTS)
FROM XML_FAKAdres2017  as Sale 
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Sales'),ELEMENTS
```